# Extracting emails and url( link) from SharePoint Pages

Tags: power-automate

I woud like to iterate through pages in SharePoint and get/extact any emails or urls and export it to an excel format.
Which tool will work best?
Power Automate Desktop or Power Automate Online?

Thanks in Advance